# using both Babel and Razor in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, webpack, razor, babeljs

I'm trying to find a way of using Razor inside a JavaScript file that is pre-compiled using Babel.

We currently have a few .cshtml files which leverage Razor to handle translations like so:
`console.log('@Translate("textHere")')`

We now also need to support IE11. Ideally, this would be done with Babel so that we can continue to use ES6 syntax.

The dominant method I have found online for using Babel involves pre-compiling .js files with babel and webpack when the service is started. However, if we were to use .js files we would no longer have access to Razor.
Even if we were to somehow get Babel to pre-compile our .cshtml files, I'm fairly sure that Babel would claim that our Razor was invalid JS syntax and would still not pre-compile the scripts.

One option I did find was that Babel does offer a mechanism for compiling `<script>` tags in the browser instead of pre-compiling. However, this also understandably came with the note:

> Compiling in the browser has a fairly limited use case, so if you are working on a production site you should be precompiling your scripts server-side.

I have also seen some arguments against using Razor for JavaScript rendering due to it preventing our .js files from being cached on the client-side, increasing repeated load times.

Should we be using both Babel and Razor?
If so, what would be the best strategy for using both Babel and Razor in JavaScript?

Comment: What eval things are you trying to do with Razor in a JS-file?

Comment: The most common and useful example is the `@Translate()` method we use for translating text in-line in the JavaScript.

Comment: There are better solutions for [i18n in JS](https://www.google.com/search?q=i18n+js). Especially such that allow you to change language without reloading the page with a *different* script. What else?

Comment: Besides the translations, we've also started conditionally writing different JS to hide and show certain features depending on how the user's options. As well as a `@Html.Raw()` to construct the endpoints we reference for minor convenience.

Comment: @Thomas the package you linked seems to be for a ruby on rails application, which I don't believe would work for an asp.net-mvc application... Is there something I'm missing? Do you have any recommendations for asp.net-mvc?

Comment: Seems they develop in ruby but the repo contains a JS version. Simplest would be to add it [via npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/i18n-js) to your project, like all the other 3rd party JS code.